# ArgumentError in mongoid-rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, rspec-rails

When I do bundle exec rspec spec/controllers I got:

/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:521:in `extract_scope_from': You must explicitly give a scope (example, context, suite) or scope alias (each, all) when using symbols as metadata for a hook. (ArgumentError)

My Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 4', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.2'
end

group :test do
    gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'mongoid-rspec'
end
```

My spec_helper.rb:

```
# spec_helper.rb

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec

  config.before :each do
    Mongoid.purge!
  end

  require 'database_cleaner'
  config.before(:siute) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      DatabaseCleaner.orm = "mongoid"
  end

  config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

My rails_helper.rb

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|

  # ArgumentError whether the following is commented out or not
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

My spec/controllers/typer_controller_spec.rb (only file in the controllers folder)

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe TyperController, type:controller do
    describe "GET #index" do
        it "initializes properly" do
            get :index
            # nothing to test yet
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: you should attach the full stack trace

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error here

```
RSpec.describe TyperController, type:controller do
```

Change it to

```
RSpec.describe TyperController, type: :controller do
```

Comment: Yes that was a typo.  I changed it but still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake:

```
config.before(:siute) do
```

should be

```
config.before(:suite) do
```